# For what angles (and why) does the equation for finite rotation fail to work?

Tags: group-theory, rotation, representation-theory, lie-algebra

I am learning rotations and group theory/representations and my lecturer's note mentioned that:

> "The group is considered connected, but not simply connected [...] As a result, the formula for a finite rotation,
>   $R = e^{−iθ·J}$ doesn’t work for all angles."

May I ask for what angles (and why) does the above equation fail to work?

References:

1. J. Tseng, *Symmetry and Relativity,* lecture notes, 2017, page 57-58. The PDF file is available [here](http://www-pnp.physics.ox.ac.uk/~tseng/teaching/b2/b2-lectures.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't fail. The Taylor series for $\exp$ is convergent for every matrix, and the [exponential map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map_%28Lie_theory%29) $\exp: so(d)\to SO(d)$ is surjective, cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1573944/11127) math.SE post.

The exponential map $\exp$ is not injective, though, as many angle-vectors describe the same rotation.